# angular-ui bootstrap typeahead escape key causing input field value become undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble solving this which seems to be an edge case.
When I select(using keyboard or mouse) a value from typeahead's dropdown, the ng-model in the  input field gets populated just fine.

However, if I type a few letters then hit 'escape' button, the 'textFieldValue' ng-model seems to be overwritten with 'undefined' by typeahead because I didn't choose a value.

What's the best way to solve this problem? Or is it too much an edge case?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textFieldValue"
typeahead="list for list in getList($viewValue)" typeahead-editable="false">
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a temporarily value.

Assign the temp value to typeahead

```
<input type="text" ng-model="tempValue" typeahead="list for list in getList($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-editable="false" >
```

Watch on tempValue and decide whether to update the target value or not.

```
    $scope.$watch('tempValue', function(tempValue){
      if(shouldUpdateTheTargetValue(tempValue)) {
        $scope.targetValue = tempValue;   
      }
    });
```

I created a plunker for that. - http://plnkr.co/edit/r63027iRobX4skV9YK60?p=preview